# MacBook wi-fi problem

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I've got 2 identical MacBook Pros in front of me (both are 15" mid-2012 2.3GHz i7 with 16GB RAM running High Sierra).

One can see my home wi-fi network, connect to it and use it just fine..
The other one can't find it at all.

What's up with that??

(Can anyone help me connect the one that won't??)

Comment: You can first do Reset Smc, Reset Nvram on the Mac won't connect. Else verify network settings on this Mac. Proxy etc...

Comment: Done the first two - no fix..
What do you mean by 'verify' network settings?
I've typed in by hand the exact name of the network, the password and selected the WPA etc.
Thanks :)

Comment: In System Preferences /Network configuration /wifi/advanced.

Comment: Can you boot into safe mode and/or create a different user? Can you boot from an external drive/make a clean install on the faulty MB? If you do that and problems persist its very likely hardware failure. Does Bluetooth work properly? Is a WiFi card even detected (Apple logo, about this mac, system report, network))

Comment: Yes I wondered about wether the Wi-Fi card was kaput.. it IS detected - but (perhaps weirdly? I don't know..) the one that connects displays the right 'country' (I'm in Ireland temporarily) but the one that doesn't connect lists country as X3!
Also, where it says 'Firmware Version', the good one lists an 'AirPortDriver' that the other one doesn't list.. perhaps I can update the firmware somehow?? (would require a 'how to' on that if anyone feels like obliging..? - and, oh yeah, it doesn't connect to the internet just now!!) Cheers :)

Comment: BTW. I have screen grabs of the 'system report' for both wifi cards but I don't know how to attach them here... sorry